# This in codesandbox.io,create-react-app ,use strict and not use strict

Tags: javascript, this, create-react-app, codesandbox

i am new to js.
and I don’t really understand how `this` works.
I have a few examples and they work differently in  codesandbox.io,create-react-app, use strict and not  use strict.

**example 1**

```
var obj = {
    id: "awesome",
    cool: function coolFn() {
        console.log( this);
    }
};

var id = "not awesome";

obj.cool(); 

setTimeout( obj.cool, 100 );
```

in codesandbox `Object {id: "awesome", cool: function coolFn()}, null`.

in use strict  `{id: "awesome", cool: ƒ},Window{...}`.

in not use strict `{id: "awesome", cool: ƒ},Window{...}`.

in create-react-app  `{id: "awesome", cool: ƒ},Window{...}`.

**example 2**

```
var obj = {
  id: "awesome",
  cool: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

var id = "not awesome";

obj.cool();

setTimeout(obj.cool, 100);
```

in codesandbox `undefined, undefined`.

in use strict  `Window{...},Window{...}`.

in not use strict `Window{...},Window{...}`.

in create-react-app  `undefined , undefined`.

who can explain what is happening in my examples ?

Comment: [`'strict mode'` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).